# Unit testing graphics

Tags: corona-sdk, unit-testing, automated-testing

What is the standard (if there is one) method which professional games developers use to unit test (or closest equivalent) graphics output?

I am developing with Corona SDK and I would like to test the visual output of my game code. I don't believe it is reasonable to pre-generate screenshots, scene definitions or some such for comparison at the end of a test, I would like to know if there is a good testing mechanism for graphics in general.

Comment: Potentially a duplication aside, I'd personally love to see more/better options than covered previously.

Comment: Definitely. I understand that it's a tricky area to solve. It would be great to have something which can fill the void, though.

Comment: The problem here is - what would be *reasonable* tests, not just tests for sake of testing? Typically, the graphics output is just plain display of game state(and game state is testable by regular means) - the only thing you could possibly test are errors in the engine/framework itself and not your game. Generally, it should be safe to assume the engine's code is correct and tested (by numerous users).

Comment: As I understand it, the recommended method for getting more answers on a topic covered by an existing question is to offer a bounty on it. That way the answers stay in one canonical place for ease of reference and comparing, rather than scattered across multiple similar questions.